# VBA Coding - - If Cell contains a certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I know it's a recurring topic but I need please your help because my VBA code is not working
I am trying to create a loop on cell value who contain a special text inside the column (B:B):
Please find my code

```vb
Sub test ()
    Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Work").Range("B:B")
        rw = Cell.Row
        
        If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "ResourcesHIIT4") > 0 Then '
        'If Cell.Value Like "*ResourcesHIIT4*" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
      
            Sheets("Database").Select
            Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      
            Set r = Sheets("Allocation").Range("A2")
            Do While r.Value <> ""
                Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = r.Value
                Set r = r.Offset(1)
            Loop
        end if
    next 
end sub
```

I tried these 2 different codes and every time the macro goes to `end if`:

- `If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "ResourcesHIIT4") > 0 Then '`
- `If Cell.Value Like "*ResourcesHIIT4*" Then`

Could you please help me to know where is the issue?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So your cells do not contain `ResourcesHIIT4`.

Comment: If the issue is case-related you could try `If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "ResourcesHIIT4", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` or `If UCase(Cell.Value) Like UCase("*ResourcesHIIT4*") Then`. Also, you're using `r` instead of `rw` in parts of the code. You can easily avoid this by using `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: It's working :) Thanks a lot for your help. The 2 solutions that you propose are working :)